# Form submission is not working in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url("contact")?>">
    Full Name :

    <input type="text" name="contact_name" class="form-control archo-square-input" required>
    <br>Email :
    <input type="text" name="contact_mail" class="form-control archo-square-input" required/>
    <br>Message :
    <textarea class="form-control archo-square-input" name="contact_message" required></textarea>
    <br>

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info archo-square-input" />

</form>
```

PHP:

`Index` function of `Contact` controller

```
public function index()
{
   if (isset($_POST['contact_name'])){

        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

        $name=$_POST["contact_name"];
        $mail=$_POST["contact_mail"];
        $subject="Contact Messages";
        $message = "
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>Email From ".$name."</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <p>".$_POST["contact_message"]."</p>
                    <p>Mail :".$mail." </p>
                 </body>
           </html>
        ";

        if(mail($mail,$subject, $message,$headers)){
            $data['message']='success';
        }else{
            $data['message']='error';
        }

    }else{
        $data['message']='';
    }

    $data['all_albums']=$this->contact_model->get_all_albums();
    $this->template->build('contact_view',$data);
}
```

I know this is a silly problem and I did that kind of work many many time. But God knows why this is not working. Please help. Thanks in advance.

**NOTE** : one told me that can be a problem of .htaccess .Is it possible?

Comment: Whats your url structure? How you currently enter urls to view pages?

Comment: domain/controller/function/value

Comment: have you tried naming your submit button? `input type="submit" name="submit"`, then on your controller, `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){}`, and then just a simple echo the exit inside? try it first.

Comment: tried it a long time ago.But didn't Help.@kevinabelita

Comment: try like this action="<?php echo base_url()?>contact/index".

Answer (score 0):

try this on your htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^/(index\.php|assets/|humans\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

and change your config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: try this $post = $this->input->post(); var_dump($post); check  your values is isset or not

Comment: can you tell me why it always false? I saw the chrome development tool, the submission was perfect and data was showing there. But why bool false?@aridjemana

Answer (score 0):

When you say not working are you getting a 404 error on submit or a 500 error?
I would check that the action URL you are echoing in to the form is actually correct and then try manually browsing to it using a post simulator (many plugins for Firefox and Chrome can do this).

If you have the CodeIgniter CSRF protection enabled you might also need to include the token in your POST.

If you have a working URL for this I am happy to take a look.

Comment: You don't need to include **CSRF** protection.

Comment: Because the form has nothing to do with CSRF token. It should work fine without it.

Comment: I am not using any CSRF token in my form. Its just a regular one

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax to get your $_POST using CodeIgniter.

```
$post = $this->input->post();
$name = $post['name'];
```

Comment: I tried that at first. It was not working and thats why i started trying `$_POST[]`

Comment: There were few problems in html. Solved them all. Still not getting the bool true

Answer (score 0):

As I am using live server, the `.htaccess` is like that

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.rectangle\.com.bd$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://rectangle.com.bd/$1 [L,R=301]
```

and my `site_url()` is like that `www.rectangle.com.bd` because in my config file I have

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.rectangle.com.bd/';
```

So every time I am submitting the form it is hitting `www.rectangle.com.bd` and **redirecting** to `rectangle.com.bd` as is written on the `.htaccess` file rule. So on the redirected page i am getting no `$_POST` values. So solution is to make the `.htaccess` file like that:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^rectangle\.com.bd$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.rectangle.com.bd/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Hope it will help the folks who will encounter that kind of problem next.